# Can't export an object with "screen" blending from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, pdf

I need help with exporting on Illustrator :) Can't find an answer anywhere!

I am trying to export a large design as PDF (press quality), and I have a layer (gradient circle) with a screen blending. I noticed that when it exports as PDF, it ignores this property and I end up getting a solid shape that covers the elements.

Attached below how it looks like when I export as PDF (tried different settings, PDF 1.3, 1.4 etc) and a screenshot from the program of how it supposed to look like. It looks fine if I export as JPEG...

Any ides how to solve this and export it for print with the screen blending property?
[image]

[image: This is how it looks like on the program]

Answer (score 2):

Some blending modes can **not** be achieved with ink on paper (CMYK). `Screen` is one such mode (as is Overlay, dodge, etc) You can't "lighten" an ink by placing another ink on top of it.

If your Illustrator Document Color Mode **is** CMYK, this failure in the `Screen` blending mode *should* have been visible the moment you set the mode to `Screen`. You *must* be working in RGB. If you are outputting to CMYK, it's best to *work* in CMYK. Primarily so you get a closer representation of what any output may look like.

To fix your issue, you can try **Flattening transparency** in the file. (`Object > Flatten Transparency`). This may or may not work well for your particular artwork.

The other option is to restructure the art so that you do **not** use the `Screen` blending mode.

Since the file must be in RGB color mode, you could also try copy/pasting the art into Photoshop, or placing it into Photoshop as a smart object, Convert to CMYK there and Photoshop *should* do a decent job of converting the existing RGB artwork to CMYK. Photoshop sort of pseudo-flattens transparency upon conversion to CMYK. (Photoshop has an underlying RIP to process stuff like this. Illustrator does not.) This will result in a raster image rather than vector, but if the PPI is correct that may not make any real difference.